# Rename recursively files, while keeping the extension

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, rename

I have a bunch of directories that each hold one *.txt file in it (and other non *.txt files).

I'd like to rename those files recursively from the command line, basically *.txt to info.txt.
So all *.txt files should be renamed to info.txt.
There is always only one .txt file in each directory.

I have been looking at multiple questions here (and elsewhere) that seem similar, but either they focus to change the extension, or they do not work recursively,...

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Platform: Linux or MacOSX.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find ~/dir -type f -name "*.txt" -not -name "info.txt" \
           -execdir mv -v {} info.txt \;
```

Alternatively:

```
find ~/dir -type f -name "*.txt" -not -name "info.txt" \
| while read -r file; do
    mv "$file" "${file%/*}/info.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response ... this worked like a charm!! :) (without the \ at the end of the first line - but that's me not paying attention when doing a copy/paste)

Comment: @Hanzaplastique The ``\`` escapes the newline, so you can copy-paste the entire code block to your terminal, or into a shell script.

Comment: Note that `-execdir` is not specified by POSIX, so not all versions of `find` will have it. This will certainly work on most linuxes, since they tend to use GNU find, but I don't know if whatever version OSX uses has `-execdir` (you may need to use the POSIX-specified-but-less-safe `-exec` instead).

Comment: It would have to be modified a fair bit for `-exec`.

Comment: @evilsoup BSD `find` has the `execdir` option, so it works on OS X as well. grawity, shouldn't the `find … | while` use a `find … -print0 | while read -d '' …`? (But then we're not POSIXy anymore I guess…)

Comment: The \ caused an error message on MacOSX, taking it out resolved it :-) Thanks again for the quick answer! Just wished I would have counted on those stupid hidden MacOS files (like ._info.txt).

Comment: Note for Mac users: `find . -name "._*" -exec rm '{}' \;` will remove those.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) utility from Ubuntu, which accepts a Perl expression to modify the file names.

```
find . -iname "*.txt" | rename "s/[^\/]+\.txt$/info.txt/"
```

Comment: Which `rename` does this apply to? Also note that this will most probably break if files or paths contain spaces.

Comment: I don't know the version, there's no -v option. I tested it on Ubuntu 12.04 and it works, even if the a file has space in its name or path, since find doesn't escape spaces. I prefer the grawity's solution, but I didn't read it before.

Comment: I'm just asking because there exist various tools that call themselves `rename`, e.g. http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/ and http://ss64.com/bash/rename.html.

Comment: It's exactly this one: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html I think it's a tool provided by perl guys.

Comment: Yet another one :) I added a link to that manpage to your post in case someone gets confused over the options.

Answer (score 0):

grawity's answer is the fastest way and maybe the more "correct" one, but there are also some GUI based tools that can perform file renaming tasks with an easy interface and support for regular expressions: [Krename](http://www.krename.net/) (KDE based), [GPRename](http://gprename.sourceforge.net/) and [pyRenamer](http://www.infinicode.org/code/pyrenamer/) (Gnome base).